# Need to store a value in an array

Tags: java, arrays, string, arraylist, split

I need to store a value in an array if the condition is not matched otherwise it should take the values after splitting a string with respect to a space. my code snippet is given below:

```
ArrayList<String> InOutsNum = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> InOutsFinal = new ArrayList<String>();
String[] strTemp = new String[2];
String temp = "[3:0] data1";
strTemp = temp.split(" ");
if(strTemp[1].isEmpty()) {      // TODO
  strTemp[1] = strTemp[0];
  strTemp[0] = "1";
}
InOutsNum.add(strTemp[0]);
InOutsFinal.add(strTemp[1]);
```

Please help!

*Output:*

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
```

Comment: if i give new String[2], still it does not change the output.

Comment: Ah, you're right, you immediately throw the array away and replace it.  Once I fix the syntax errors, your code works fine for me.

Comment: Please post the entire stack trace, and indicate the line with is throwing the exception.  Also, please post your *actual* code, what you've got in your question has syntax errors in the declaration of the array lists, and doesn't compile, so it can't be what you're actually running.

Comment: Also, why do you check to see if the array is empty?  You've hardcoded its contents, so it will always contain `["[3:0]", "data1"]`.

Answer (score 3):

If you use split, there is no need to indicate the array size first.

You could do:

```
String[] tokens = temp.split(" ");
```

Comment: This doesn't address the OP's problem, in which they claim that they're getting an out of bounds exception based on the contents of the array after they assign it the output of `temp.split(" ");`

Comment: **Remarks:** To check number of tokens received, you can do `tokens.length`. `token[0]` will be `[3:0]` and `token[1]` will be `data1`.

Comment: @azurefrog It does address the problem because there won't be OutOfBoundsException anymore if OP use the above code.

Comment: There isn't an out of bounds exception with their existing code, either.  Try dropping it into an IDE and running it.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
ArrayList<String> InOutsNum = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> InOutsFinal = new ArrayList<String>();
    String[] strTemp; //no need to declare because *
    String temp = "[3:0] data1";//*here you set the array
    strTemp = temp.split(" ");
    if(strTemp[1].isEmpty()) {      // TODO
        strTemp[1] = strTemp[0];
        strTemp[0] = "1";
    }
    InOutsNum.add(strTemp[0]);   //Contains "[3:0]"
    InOutsFinal.add(strTemp[1]); //Contains "data1"
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a check for the length of your array first to determine if you can access a field or not.

use the below code:

```
if(strTemp.length>=2 && strTemp[1].isEmpty()) {
```

Also as per the suggestion if you are storing values from split(" ") method in the temp array you dont need to intialize it before.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to use two arrays, like :

```
String[] strTemp = new String[2];
String temp = "[3:0] data1";
String[] splitted = temp.split(" ");
if(splitted.length  == 1) {      // TODO
  strTemp[1] = splitted[0];
  strTemp[0] = "1";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Even if you are initializing or not the array will be replaced by the result of split().

i think following cod will work fine for you

```
ArrayList<String> InOutsNum = new ArrayList<String>();

ArrayList<String> InOutsFinal = new ArrayList<String>();

String[] strTemp = new String[2];

String temp = "[3:0] data1";
// temp.trim(); better to include this
if(temp.indexOf(' ')==-1)
{
 strTemp[1] = temp; //can be replaced by InOutsNum.add(temp);

  strTemp[0] = "1"; //can be replaced by InOutsFinal.add("1"); if you don't want the array values

}
else
{
strTemp = temp.split(" ");
InOutsNum.add(strTemp[0]);  
InOutsFinal.add(strTemp[1]);

//even this can be replaced by using substring functions like
//int index=temp.indexOf(' ');
//InOutsNum.add(temp.substring(0,index));  
//InOutsFinal.add(temp.substring(0,temp.indexOf(' ',index+1)));


}
```

These lengthy codes can be avoided by using conditional operators also(:?)